# Does 'sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential gcc' download gcc and all its prerequisites

Tags: apt, 16.04

Is the following command

`sudo apt-get build-dep build-essential gcc`

the correct way to download gcc and all its prerequisites (and prerequisites's prerequisites and so on)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposal is overkill!

- `gcc` is preinstalled in Ubuntu by default
- the `build-essential` [package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/build-essential) contains `gcc`
- `build-dep` attempts to pull in packages required to build the selected packages from source but you do not need to do that to use them

**Conclusion**

To install `gcc` in Ubuntu you don't need to do anything at all.